# how to set each LI tooltip to its A childs href attribute?

Tags: jquery

I have this line working, but it sets all list items tooltip to the very first items href. So they all say google.com.

```
 $("li").attr('title', $(this).find("a").attr("href"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$("li").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).find("a").attr("href"))
})
```

Comment: Worked perfect! Thank you. I forgot .each like a fool. Ill accept this as right answer

Answer (score 1):

Use a `callback`:

```
$("li").attr('title', function() { return $(this).find("a").attr("href"); });
```